# How to serialize a list to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I need to serialize the query from my database into a Json format which looks like this:

```
    {
         Facilities:[
                {
                FacilityID:".....",
                desc:"....."
                },
                ....
        ]
    }
```

However, i cant seemed to get the Facilities json array in my codes. How do i edit my codes to show the Facilities? Please Help, Thank you.
My output now:

```
    [
                {
                FacilityID:".....",
                desc:"....."
                },
                ....
    ]
```

Not sure how does it works if i added this code:

```
    Public class FacList
    {
       public List<FacObject> Facilities;
    }
```

Creating of getters and setters

```
    public class FacObject
    {
        public string facilityID { get; set; }
        public string departmentID { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string block { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string openHours { get; set; }
        public string closeHours { get; set; }
        public string maxBkTime { get; set; }
        public string maxBkUnits { get; set; }
        public string minBkTime { get; set; }
        public string minBkUnits { get; set; }

        public FacObject(string facid, string depid, string desc, string b, string l, string n
            ,string o ,string c, string maxt, string maxu, string mint, string minu)
        {
            this.facilityID = facid;
            this.departmentID = depid;
            this.description = desc;
            this.block = b;
            this.level = l;
            this.name = n;
            this.openHours = o;
            this.closeHours = c;
            this.maxBkTime = maxt;
            this.maxBkUnits = maxu;
            this.minBkTime = mint;
            this.minBkUnits = minu;
        }
    }
```

Below is my code which queries from the database and serializes the list of facilities into a json string and passes back to the caller! Please help and advice! Help would be appreaciated:)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //To get the string to search in facility table
        string departmentID = Request.QueryString["DepartmentID"];
        string block = Request.QueryString["Block"];
        string level = Request.QueryString["Level"];
        string name = Request.QueryString["Name"];

        //creates a list of fac object
        List<FacObject> sqlFacList = new List<FacObject>();
        //test if correct 
        //Only select from a certain department
        //select the database for the list of facility that contains 
        //block, level, name (%)
        using (var db = new KioskContext())
        {
            var facilitys = from f in db.Facilitys
                            where f.Department.DepartmentID == departmentID
                            && (f.Block.Contains(block) && f.Level.Contains(level)
                            && f.Name.Contains(name))

                            orderby f.FacilityID
                            select new { f.FacilityID, f.DepartmentID, f.Description, f.Block,
                            f.Level, f.Name, f.OpenHours, f.CloseHours, f.MaxBkTime, f.MaxBkUnits, f.MinBkTime, f.MinBkUnits};

            foreach (var fac in facilitys)
            {
                FacObject facobject = new FacObject(fac.FacilityID, fac.DepartmentID, fac.Description, fac.Block, fac.Level,
                    fac.Name, fac.OpenHours, fac.CloseHours, fac.MaxBkTime, fac.MaxBkUnits, fac.MinBkTime, fac.MinBkUnits);
                sqlFacList.Add(facobject);
            }
        }

        //Serialize into json format output (string)
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sqlFacList, Formatting.Indented);


        //codes to pass back the json string to the iPad
        Response.Write(json);
    }
```

Comment: Is this using Web API 2 and MVC? If so, pass the list back to your controller and use `return Json<List<FacObject>>(yourList);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are on the right track. You mentioned in your post you created a class FacList but in your code you are not using it. The example below uses that class produces the exact JSON you're looking for:

**Sample code:**

```
var sqlFacList = new FacList();
sqlFacList.Facilities = new List<FacObject>();
sqlFacList.Facilities.Add( new FacObject() { facilityID = "12" });
sqlFacList.Facilities.Add(new FacObject() { facilityID = "34" });
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sqlFacList, Formatting.Indented);
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "Facilities": [
    {
      "facilityID": "12",
      "departmentID": null,
      "description": null,
      "block": null,
      "level": null,
      "name": null,
      "openHours": null,
      "closeHours": null,
      "maxBkTime": null,
      "maxBkUnits": null,
      "minBkTime": null,
      "minBkUnits": null
    },
    {
      "facilityID": "34",
      "departmentID": null,
      "description": null,
      "block": null,
      "level": null,
      "name": null,
      "openHours": null,
      "closeHours": null,
      "maxBkTime": null,
      "maxBkUnits": null,
      "minBkTime": null,
      "minBkUnits": null
    }
  ]
}
```